# Change cursor to Hand icon when hover over the menu item in popup

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I need to show handicon when hover over the menu items.I tried with `SystemMouseCursors.click` but it didn't works.It still show cursor

[image]

```
void showPopUpMenuAtTap(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details,controller) {
    showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        details.globalPosition.dx,
        details.globalPosition.dy,
        details.globalPosition.dx,
        details.globalPosition.dy,
      ), items: [
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
        mouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,

        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,

          child: ListTile(
            minLeadingWidth : 10,
            leading:SvgPicture.asset(Images.deleteGreyIcon), // your icon
            title: Text("Delete"),
          ), value: '1'),
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
          mouseCursor:MouseCursor.uncontrolled,

          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: ListTile(
            minLeadingWidth : 10,
            leading: SvgPicture.asset(Images.editIcon), // your icon
            title: Text("Rename"),
          ), value: '2'),

    ],
      elevation: 3.0,).then((value) {
      if (value == null) return;
      if(value == "1"){

       }else if(value == "2"){
      
      }

    });
    

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

LisTile provides mouse cursor property. so add like below,

```
 ListTile(
              mouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
              minLeadingWidth : 10
              leading:SvgPicture.asset(Images.deleteGreyIcon), 
              title: Text("Delete"),
            ),
```

Comment: Just a comment for clarity. Most of the time you can wrap widgets with MouseRegion to show the pointer, but this does not work with ListTile. This answer is the correct solution. Use the mouseCursor property on ListTile instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ListTile with MouseRegion:

```
MouseRegion(
      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
      child: ListTile(...),
          ),
```

Comment: I tried that way too. But still shows the same.

Comment: MouseRegion does not work with ListTile. This works for other widgets but not ListTile.